# Use Json data file on Flutter unit test

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I would like to do the unit test for model by Flutter.
Then I want to use test json data.

But I got the error message.
`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast`

I want to know how to solve this issue.

Here is the test codes.

```
void main() {
  group('Gift Test', () {
    test('Gift model test', () {
      final file = File('json/gift_test.json').readAsStringSync();
      final gifts = Gift.fromJson(jsonDecode(file) as Map<String, dynamic>);

      expect(gifts.id, 999);
    });
  });
}
```

Here is the model

```
@freezed
abstract class Gift with _$Gift {
  @Implements(BaseModel)
  const factory Gift({
    int id,
    String name,
    int amount,
    Image image,
  }) = _Gift;

  factory Gift.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$GiftFromJson(json);
}
```

And this is the test data.

```
[
  {
    "id": 999,
    "name": "testest",
    "amount": 30000,
    "image": {
      "id": 9999,
      "image": {
        "url": "https://text.jpg",
      },
    },
  }
]
```

Comment: The problem is that in the json file you have a List so dart is inferring it is a List<dymanic> you can either remove the [] from the /gift_test.json, or iterate over it and do a test over each one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json file is a list, not an object, either you change your json file in

```json
  {
    "id": 999,
    "name": "testest",
    "amount": 30000,
    "image": {
      "id": 9999,
      "image": {
        "url": "https://text.jpg",
      },
    },
  }
```

Or you will need to update your code to take the first element of the list:

```dart
final file = File('json/gift_test.json').readAsStringSync();
final gifts = Gift.fromJson((jsonDecode(file) as List).first as Map<String, dynamic>);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works!
Why do I have to cast the List?

Comment: Your Json file has its object inside a list (your file starts with `[` and ends with `]`). So when you decode it, you get a `List` and you need to cast it to be able to use `.first` on it.